# unable to write to the csv file

Tags: r

I have a data frame which I am trying to write to csv file as this:

```
write.csv(data_df, file = "dev.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in if (inherits(X[[j]], "data.frame") && ncol(xj) > 1L) X[[j]] <- as.matrix(X[[j]]) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: Please show us ``dput(head(data_df))`` in your main question

Comment: it may be because some to fthe column names has "." in them like "agentVersion.sourceRevisio"